# Connection String Authentication Change

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I changed My Authentication mode to SQL authentication to windows authentication
so this error occurred.

System.ComponentModel.win32Exception:no process on the other end of the pipe

At This Line:tblUser

```
logedInUser = _dbRepository.GetEntities().FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserName == model.UserName && m.Password == model.Password);
```

this is my connection string:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.TransportMSDB.csdl|res://*/DB.TransportMSDB.ssdl|res://*/DB.TransportMSDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-DB5NQJ7\RIDDHISH;initial catalog=TMS;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

And I also enabled pipe, TCP/Ip protocol

Comment: Whats not working? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: it gives me an errors like System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.' basically i am transfer my project from a company server to my laptop and my laptop's sql server authentication is window type which i convert to mix mode but still this error occured and it also have some times  four errors

Comment: Please add all new details to the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update connection string in edmx (app.config) file and web.config file.